# BUG in SBJsonParser

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using `JSON.h` to parse my strings to an object. Always work fine, but this day, happen this error while try to parse with function `[strJSON JSONValue]` : -JSONValue failed. Error trace is:

> "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=10 \"Garbage after JSON\" UserInfo=0xd3076b0     {NSLocalizedDescription=Garbage after JSON}"

So when I was debugging to know what happen I put a breakpoint in function `- (id)fragmentWithString:(id)repr` and my code was entering in this line:

```
// We found some valid JSON. But did it also contain something else?
if (![self scanIsAtEnd]) {
    [self addErrorWithCode:ETRAILGARBAGE description:@"Garbage after JSON"];
    return nil;
}
```

and return me that error I thought. What does it mean? Why when I comment this line of code:

```
if (![self scanIsAtEnd]) {
    [self addErrorWithCode:ETRAILGARBAGE description:@"Garbage after JSON"];
    return nil;
}
```

why does my code works fine when comment that line?

Comment: That error is because of @"Garbage after JSON". You should check the json you are passing on to this.

Comment: @ACB thank you...json was wrong with ; at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in error message, that error is because of "Garbage after JSON". You should check the json you are passing on to this. Mostly that contains some garbage at the end or it is not formatted properly at the end.

Comment: you are right. The json was correct but it was with ; at the end. =( That's why, happens this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that after it found the end of the JSON object, there was more data in the input that you gave it. This could mean that you literally have non-JSON data at the end of the string. Or it could mean that you have unbalanced braces (and therefore have an extra brace at the end of the string that is considered garbage).

For example, this JSON has garbage at the end:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2
    }
}
}
```